# Para que servem os parametros "User" e "CancellationToken"?

Tags: c#, .net, token, google-drive-api

Estou fazendo uma implementação com a `API` do Google Drive, e no bloco de código:

```
 credenciais = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(diretorioCredenciais, true)).Result;
```

Que serve para obter as credenciais, existem os parametros: `"user"` e `CancellationToken.None`, gostaria de saber.

- O que são eles?
- Para que servem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [parâmetro `user` é o nome do usuário](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.3/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker#a75a651cb8b58b9293e7b9e2eb35db452) que deseja usar para acessar o recurso e o [`cancellationToken`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é usado para poder pedir para a execução ser interrompida. Não pode qualquer código fazer isto, precisa ser um que criou esta rotina assíncrona, por isso existe um *token* que é uma espécie de senha que permite a operação.

Comment: Estou procurando uma forma onde eu não precise confirmar meu usuário. O Parametro `user` está relacionado a isso? Não consegui entender.

Comment: Você quer criar uma credencial, mas não quer fornecer um usuário?

Comment: O Contrario,  estou sendo redirecionado para a pagina do google para confirmar o email. O que quero é enviar o email da conta junto com a requisição, pra evitar ter de confirmar.

Comment: Aí já é outro problema.